# Problems with SQL Connection in Java

Tags: java, database, exception, jdbc, connection

Alright, so I've decided to follow a tutorial on Youtube about `SQL` databases, and I created a database on PhpMyAdmin then exported (what I think is a table, not the entire database) an `SQL` backup file `(customers.sql)` to my desktop. I want to connect to it using JDBC, and I tried it with the code below.(note that I ensured that the driver was installed correctly with `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` For debugging purposes please assume that only the file exists on my desktop, I have the driver, the following code, and nothing else. Also, I'm not sure how to get the `sql` file on `localhost`.

```
Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customers","root", "");
```

This code generated an exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown database 'customers'
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:370)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1038)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:925)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication(MysqlIO.java:1704)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1250)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2467)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2500)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2285)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:818)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:31)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:395)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:317)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:579)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:221)
at com.gmail.PhysicistSarah.TestProject.Database.DatabaseDriver.<init>(DatabaseDriver.java:32)
at com.gmail.PhysicistSarah.TestProject.Core.Main.databaseTrial(Main.java:99)
at com.gmail.PhysicistSarah.TestProject.Core.Main.main(Main.java:49)
```

Comment: check for your database spelling in mysql
by show database;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't connect to a SQL file. A SQL file is just that: a file, with some text inside. If you want to connect to a MySQL database running on localhost, you need to install MySQL on your machine, start it, create a database, create tables in it, and populate the tables.

Follow the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index.html) for how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Error clearly mentions that you don't have a database called 'customers'. Make sure that you have the database in mysql before connecting it through jdbc. Or maybe some typo errors in schema name in mysql or in jdbc code.

Answer (score 0):

check for your `(customers)`database spelling in `mysql database` by 
 query `show databases;` if it display your `customers` database then copy that name and put in your java code. other wise create by firing a query `create database customers;`